# Shift register library design

Tags: c++, object-oriented, inheritance

I am creating a small library for controlling bars of leds and have some doubts about my design.

I have 2 basic entities in the design so far:

BarService (and implementation)

```
template<class T>

class BarService{
public:
  virtual void turnOnLeds(T* bar, int end) = 0;
```

```
class PinBarService : public BarService<PinBar>{
public:
  virtual void turnOnLeds(PinBar* bar, int end);
  void initPins(PinBar* bar);
};
```

```
class OpampService : public BarService<OpampBar>{
public:
  virtual void turnOnLeds(OpampBar* bar, int end);
  void initPins(OpampBar* bar);
};
```

Bar models:

```
class Bar{
private:
  int ledCount;
public:
  Bar(int ledCount);
  int getLedCount();
};
```

```
class BasicBar : public Bar{
private:
  int* pins;
public:
  BasicBar(int ledCount, int pins[]);
  int getPin(int index);
};
```

```
class OpampBar : public Bar{
private:
  int input;
public:
  OpampBar(int ledCount, int input);
};
```

My reasoning for separating these is that I feel the Bar models should only contain information about themselves, thus allowing me to create more classes later on which use that information rather than having the bar itself perform actions (like writing to hardware).

The reason I'm having doubts is that by using templates every implementation of the service needs to accept a different model.

My question comes down to: Am I going overboard with separating the model from its actions? and are templates a good solution here? and overall, what could be improved about this design?

Answer (score 1):

Generally "template vs polymorphism" is a complex topic. A simple rule of thumb: if it is high level (e.g., service you instantiate a few times) go virtual, if it is low level (you need to create a array of million these objects) then go template.

In your case... honestly your interface makes little sense to me - it is difficult to make any advices.

Say, is there any point in `Bar` class? It simply holds an `int` and serves no other purpose. Just having a common function and variable doesn't imply that you need to have a shared basic class. If it had virtual destructor then I could understand to a certain degree.

Why `OpampBar` is a class? It just holds two integers. Why not make it a struct with public members? Why make it unnecessarily complicated?

What is this `BasicBar` and what is this `pins` raw pointer? Is it a pointer to an array? A pointer to data that doesn't belong to it? Why not use `std::vector<int>`? There are lots of well made classes and functions in STL, why not utilize them?

What is the point of `BarService`? It is an interface class. I know of two purposes of interface classes: (1) To allow your program to switch between different derived classes easily. (2) Hide implementation. Is this the case? (Well, it can also serve as poor man's `concept` substitude... but I doubt that you use any SFINAE).

You need to watch and read tutorials on C++. There are plenty for free - just google it. There are lots of CppCon videos on YouTube where they explain additions to C++ (you gotta learn what was added in C++11/14 as well as what STL already had for 20 years).

Comment: In an embedded system it Is often prefered or even the only viable way to avoid dynamic memory allocation. Maybe thats why array Is used instead of std::vector...

Comment: @slepic if you want to limit dynamic allocation then one can use `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` and utilize move operations.

Comment: But wouldn't that still do dynamic memory allocation? unique_ptr just handles the deallocation for you once the unique_ptr is destroyed. Isnt't it true, that it can't help if you wanted to avoid dynamic memory allocation entirely, not just limit it?

Comment: @slepic it would be in a more controlled fashion - so you can pass buffers around. Or you want a system where there is no dynamic allocation at all? I mean, in this case I doubt you can use anything beyond C.

Comment: Not true. You can still use classes, parameter overloading, all the fancy stuff. Dynamic does not mean OOP. Dynamic just means you decide (the amount/type of objects to create - the amount of memory to allocate) at runtime. But you can still put all that stuff on the stack as long as you know the number and types of objects you create at compile time. And OP never stated anything that implies he need to allocate variable amount of objects, nor create any objects of polymorphic type which he could not determine at compile time.

Comment: @slepic you throw away almost everything there is in STL library - except for a few classes. I doubt that anyone would bother making a C++ implementation for such a limited system. In the worst case make a custom allocator that takes lots of space on the stack and simply use classes via this allocator. But if this is possible why can't `new` work in the first place?

Comment: Also not true. Many things in STL dont rely on dynamic memory. C++ has many implementations for such limited systems. It Is commonly used in such systems. And most importantly just because a feature exist doesnt mean you have to use it. dynamic memory allocation Is only reasonable in cases i already mentioned. And for example `array<>` is STL container without dynamic allocation.

Comment: Anyway, it doesnt have to be the case that dynamic memory is not avalable. There is just no reason to use it in OPs case. And why would I implement a custom allocator if allocation on stack as local variable is perfectly fine for given use case? Embedded systems usualy dont need that dynamic memory. They operate over a fixed set of components, chips have a fixed amount of pins, and so on. It's not like new LEDs are suddenly going to spawn in the system. Nor the chip is going to offspring a new pin...

Comment: I think you have blown your head with all the new stuff in the language And Are So keen on using it that you forgot to reason about when it Is appropriate. Hammer Is not Always the right Tool for a job... Although i knew a Guy WHO used pickaxe for everything And He seemd fine with that but thats another Story :)

Comment: @slipic you aren't too bright, are you? Find me the poor fellow who needs to implement the whole C++ standart for system that have no dynamic allocation - no threads, no nothing. And all for what? It's easier to write in assembly those led controllers.

Comment: Nevertheless the Real world shows us that C++ has Been implemented for such platforms And it Is commonly used on such platforms. And no, it Is not easier in assembler. Assembler Is So low level that it makes it hard to understand the code ať first glance. Use assembler if you want the best performance And remove every single unneeded instruction.

Comment: Hmm so now I need threads to controll LEDs? Interesting. Nobody ever said everything from STL has to be implemented on those platforms. Do you always use every single feature of a library you pull in to your project? I doubt so. Embedded systems usualy dont have capabilities to have threads. And so the threads component doesnt have to be implemented on such platform. C++ has a lot to offer apart from STL and so it is still worth it. Now lets even assume that dynamic memory is available. Give me one good reason to use dynamic memory in OPs case and I will shut up...

Comment: @slepic C++ is used for embedded but it is only in your imagination that dynamic allocation cannot be called.

Comment: I didnt say cannot. I say it is not necesary until you need dynamic amount of objects or objects of type not known at compile time. They usualy have a limited amount of memory and so it is wise to only use it when no other option is available. Im still wating for your explanation why using the implicit stack is not an option here.